# Rails routing and Knock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

This question may be a bit trivial, but I'm new in rails.
I use [Knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) to authenticate api users with JWT, and my `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :news_articles

  mount Knock::Engine => "/sessions"
end
```

According to knock docs, it creates a route 'POST /sessions/auth_token', how can i alias 'POST /sessions/auth_token' to just 'POST /sessions' via rails conf?

Comment: a similar thing happens with devise, i think the approach there is to copy their controller code into your app and then route to the controller containing it.

Comment: @maxpleaner copying seems not the best solution to me. But now it works in a such way in my project. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version (1.5) of [knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) doesn't need the engine to be mounted anymore.

Instead you can run the token controller generator

```
$ rails generate knock:token_controller user
```

This will add the following in `config/routes.rb`

```
post 'user_token' => 'user_token#create'
```

You can simply modify this route to fit your needs.